# Обновление альфа версии не доступно в play market

Tags: android, google-play-console

Приложение уже выпущено код версии 11
Создаю новое закрытое-альфа тестирование код версии 15
Приглашение на тестирование подтвердил. Уведомление что "Новая версия ... успешно опубликована в google play" получил.
Перехожу в плеймеркет но новая версия недоступна, только 2 кнопки "удалить", "открыть". Возле названия приложения появилось слово в скобках (бета) но я хочу протестировать альфу при чем тут бета?

В [официальной документации](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) есть такой пункт:
**Примечание.** Вы больше не сможете создавать открытые альфа-тестирования или закрытые бета-тестирования, но у вас сохранится доступ к тем, которые уже выпущены.

Но у меня закрытое альфа-тестирование.
Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Приложение изначально ставилось из PlayMarket? Кэш сбрасывался?

Answer (score 1):

По удалял списки тестировщиков из всех релизов (альфа, бета...) опять добавил список тестировщиков в альфу, заработало.